# Ubuntu 18.04 WiFi access not authenticating

Tags: 16.04, wireless, 18.04, network-manager

I've had this problem since 16.04 and hoped it would resolve itself in 18.04.  Since it hasn't, I'm making this post:

My **GalagoPro running Ubuntu 18.04** connects at home without issue.  Username and Password and without issue, I connect on home WiFi.  Hotel WiFi, I connect without issue...  Again, username and PW, and I'm on.

For whatever reason, it's not so simple in a specific university WiFi network.  I am able to connect my iPhone without issue to it, Username and Password...no issues.  But Ubuntu 18.04(and 16.04 for that matter) refuses to authenticate on this specific network.

I go into the security tab (Network Settings) and my eyes bleed.  Can someone help me navigate these settings?  Is there a guide out there?  Honestly, I'm thinking it shouldn't be this hard to get on a wifi...  the iPhone seems to keep it simple, why not Ubuntu?  *shrugs*

EDIT::

Are you familiar with the settings on the wireless router? What security is setup there?

I have  no idea.  That being said, if there are specific questions I should be asking the IT department, let me know.

```
Oct  3 17:51:06 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
Oct  3 17:51:08 Galago-Pro kernel: [  108.871680] wlp59s0:     deauthenticating from 40:e3:d6:91:42:52 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Oct  3 17:51:08 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: Authentication with 40:e3:d6:91:42:52 timed out.
Oct  3 17:51:08 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=40:e3:d6:91:42:52 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Oct  3 17:51:08 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="UCLA WPA" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=AUTH_FAILED
Oct  3 17:51:08 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <warn>  [1538614268.5247] sup-iface[0x5568138a4a40,wlp59s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Oct  3 17:51:08 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614268.5286] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Oct  3 17:51:08 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614268.6312] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct  3 17:51:20 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="UCLA WPA"
Oct  3 17:51:20 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 40:e3:d6:91:42:42 (SSID='UCLA WPA' freq=2437 MHz)
Oct  3 17:51:20 Galago-Pro kernel: [  121.088123] wlp59s0: authenticate with 40:e3:d6:91:42:42
Oct  3 17:51:20 Galago-Pro kernel: [  121.090127] wlp59s0: send auth to 40:e3:d6:91:42:42 (try 1/3)
Oct  3 17:51:20 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614280.7312] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Oct  3 17:51:20 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: Trying to associate with 40:e3:d6:91:42:42 (SSID='UCLA WPA' freq=2437 MHz)
Oct  3 17:51:20 Galago-Pro kernel: [  121.151818] wlp59s0: authenticated
Oct  3 17:51:20 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614280.7966] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Oct  3 17:51:20 Galago-Pro kernel: [  121.156090] wlp59s0: associate with 40:e3:d6:91:42:42 (try 1/3)
Oct  3 17:51:20 Galago-Pro kernel: [  121.162558] wlp59s0: RX AssocResp from 40:e3:d6:91:42:42 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
Oct  3 17:51:20 Galago-Pro kernel: [  121.195672] wlp59s0: associated
Oct  3 17:51:20 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: Associated with 40:e3:d6:91:42:42
Oct  3 17:51:20 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Oct  3 17:51:20 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614280.8417] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Oct  3 17:51:20 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
Oct  3 17:51:21 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25 -> NAK
Oct  3 17:51:21 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
Oct  3 17:51:23 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: Authentication with 40:e3:d6:91:42:42 timed out.
Oct  3 17:51:23 Galago-Pro kernel: [  123.918855] wlp59s0: deauthenticating from 40:e3:d6:91:42:42 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Oct  3 17:51:23 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=40:e3:d6:91:42:42 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Oct  3 17:51:23 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="UCLA WPA" auth_failures=2 duration=23 reason=AUTH_FAILED
Oct  3 17:51:23 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <warn>  [1538614283.5894] sup-iface[0x5568138a4a40,wlp59s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Oct  3 17:51:23 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614283.5947] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Oct  3 17:51:23 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614283.6959] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct  3 17:51:30 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <warn>  [1538614290.6413] device (wlp59s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
Oct  3 17:51:30 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614290.6414] device (wlp59s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct  3 17:51:30 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <warn>  [1538614290.6464] device (wlp59s0): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
Oct  3 17:51:30 Galago-Pro gnome-shell[1670]: clutter_input_focus_set_cursor_location: assertion 'clutter_input_focus_is_focused (focus)' failed
Oct  3 17:51:43 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614303.7940] settings-connection[0x55681389d360,0658501d-1b59-434d-a570-bf798ebbf94f]: write: successfully commited (keyfile: update /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/UCLA WPA (0658501d-1b59-434d-a570-bf798ebbf94f,"UCLA WPA"))
Oct  3 17:51:43 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614303.7982] device (wlp59s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct  3 17:51:43 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614303.7986] device (wlp59s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct  3 17:51:43 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614303.7989] device (wlp59s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'UCLA WPA' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Oct  3 17:51:43 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614303.7989] Config: added 'ssid' value 'UCLA WPA'
Oct  3 17:51:43 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614303.7989] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Oct  3 17:51:43 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614303.7990] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-65:300'
Oct  3 17:51:43 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614303.7990] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-EAP'
Oct  3 17:51:43 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614303.7990] Config: added 'password' value '<hidden>'
Oct  3 17:51:43 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614303.7990] Config: added 'eap' value 'LEAP'
Oct  3 17:51:43 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614303.7990] Config: added 'fragment_size' value '1266'
Oct  3 17:51:43 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614303.7990] Config: added 'identity' value '2039773'
Oct  3 17:51:43 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614303.7990] Config: added 'proactive_key_caching' value '1'
Oct  3 17:51:45 Galago-Pro kernel: [  145.699298] wlp59s0: authenticate with 40:e3:d6:90:4a:72
Oct  3 17:51:45 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 40:e3:d6:90:4a:72 (SSID='UCLA WPA' freq=5180 MHz)
Oct  3 17:51:45 Galago-Pro kernel: [  145.706868] wlp59s0: send auth to 40:e3:d6:90:4a:72 (try 1/3)
Oct  3 17:51:45 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614305.3479] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Oct  3 17:51:45 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: Trying to associate with 40:e3:d6:90:4a:72 (SSID='UCLA WPA' freq=5180 MHz)
Oct  3 17:51:45 Galago-Pro kernel: [  145.738486] wlp59s0: authenticated
Oct  3 17:51:45 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: Associated with 40:e3:d6:90:4a:72
Oct  3 17:51:45 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Oct  3 17:51:45 Galago-Pro kernel: [  145.740050] wlp59s0: associate with 40:e3:d6:90:4a:72 (try 1/3)
Oct  3 17:51:45 Galago-Pro kernel: [  145.741015] wlp59s0: RX AssocResp from 40:e3:d6:90:4a:72 (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=8)
Oct  3 17:51:45 Galago-Pro kernel: [  145.743252] wlp59s0: associated
Oct  3 17:51:45 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614305.3830] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associated
Oct  3 17:51:45 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
Oct  3 17:51:45 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25 -> NAK
Oct  3 17:51:46 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
Oct  3 17:51:48 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: Authentication with 40:e3:d6:90:4a:72 timed out.
Oct  3 17:51:48 Galago-Pro kernel: [  149.320309] wlp59s0: deauthenticating from 40:e3:d6:90:4a:72 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Oct  3 17:51:48 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=40:e3:d6:90:4a:72 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Oct  3 17:51:48 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="UCLA WPA" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=AUTH_FAILED
Oct  3 17:51:48 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <warn>  [1538614308.9718] sup-iface[0x5568138a4a40,wlp59s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Oct  3 17:51:48 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614308.9761] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Oct  3 17:51:49 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614309.0768] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="UCLA WPA"
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 40:e3:d6:90:4a:62 (SSID='UCLA WPA' freq=2462 MHz)
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro kernel: [  161.492225] wlp59s0: authenticate with 40:e3:d6:90:4a:62
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro kernel: [  161.494484] wlp59s0: send auth to 40:e3:d6:90:4a:62 (try 1/3)
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614321.1371] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro kernel: [  161.656216] wlp59s0: send auth to 40:e3:d6:90:4a:62 (try 2/3)
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro kernel: [  161.768118] wlp59s0: send auth to 40:e3:d6:90:4a:62 (try 3/3)
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro kernel: [  161.888209] wlp59s0: authentication with 40:e3:d6:90:4a:62 timed out
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614321.5775] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614321.6780] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 40:e3:d6:91:43:52 (SSID='UCLA WPA' freq=5500 MHz)
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro kernel: [  162.149920] wlp59s0: authenticate with 40:e3:d6:91:43:52
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro kernel: [  162.151719] wlp59s0: send auth to 40:e3:d6:91:43:52 (try 1/3)
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614321.7941] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: Trying to associate with 40:e3:d6:91:43:52 (SSID='UCLA WPA' freq=5500 MHz)
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro kernel: [  162.165747] wlp59s0: authenticated
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: Associated with 40:e3:d6:91:43:52
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro kernel: [  162.168155] wlp59s0: associate with 40:e3:d6:91:43:52 (try 1/3)
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro kernel: [  162.169143] wlp59s0: RX AssocResp from 40:e3:d6:91:43:52 (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=10)
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro kernel: [  162.171386] wlp59s0: associated
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614321.8284] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614321.8388] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25 -> NAK
Oct  3 17:52:01 Galago-Pro kernel: [  162.251826] wlp59s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 40:e3:d6:91:43:52
Oct  3 17:52:03 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
Oct  3 17:52:05 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: Authentication with 40:e3:d6:91:43:52 timed out.
Oct  3 17:52:05 Galago-Pro kernel: [  166.053974] wlp59s0: deauthenticating from 40:e3:d6:91:43:52 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Oct  3 17:52:05 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=40:e3:d6:91:43:52 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Oct  3 17:52:05 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="UCLA WPA" auth_failures=2 duration=26 reason=AUTH_FAILED
Oct  3 17:52:05 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <warn>  [1538614325.7064] sup-iface[0x5568138a4a40,wlp59s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Oct  3 17:52:05 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614325.7105] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Oct  3 17:52:05 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614325.8116] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct  3 17:52:08 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <warn>  [1538614328.6418] device (wlp59s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
Oct  3 17:52:08 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614328.6419] device (wlp59s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct  3 17:52:08 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <warn>  [1538614328.6472] device (wlp59s0): Activation: (wifi) asking for new secrets
Oct  3 17:52:08 Galago-Pro gnome-shell[1670]: clutter_input_focus_set_cursor_location: assertion 'clutter_input_focus_is_focused (focus)' failed
Oct  3 17:52:17 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614337.3398] settings-connection[0x55681389d360,0658501d-1b59-434d-a570-bf798ebbf94f]: write: successfully commited (keyfile: update /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/UCLA WPA (0658501d-1b59-434d-a570-bf798ebbf94f,"UCLA WPA"))
Oct  3 17:52:17 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614337.3402] device (wlp59s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct  3 17:52:17 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614337.3515] device (wlp59s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct  3 17:52:17 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614337.3518] device (wlp59s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'UCLA WPA' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Oct  3 17:52:17 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614337.3518] Config: added 'ssid' value 'UCLA WPA'
Oct  3 17:52:17 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614337.3518] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Oct  3 17:52:17 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614337.3518] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-65:300'
Oct  3 17:52:17 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614337.3519] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-EAP'
Oct  3 17:52:17 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614337.3519] Config: added 'password' value '<hidden>'
Oct  3 17:52:17 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614337.3519] Config: added 'eap' value 'LEAP'
Oct  3 17:52:17 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614337.3519] Config: added 'fragment_size' value '1266'
Oct  3 17:52:17 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614337.3519] Config: added 'identity' value '2039773'
Oct  3 17:52:17 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614337.3519] Config: added 'proactive_key_caching' value '1'
Oct  3 17:52:18 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 40:e3:d6:91:5b:c2 (SSID='UCLA WPA' freq=2412 MHz)
Oct  3 17:52:18 Galago-Pro kernel: [  179.133920] wlp59s0: authenticate with 40:e3:d6:91:5b:c2
Oct  3 17:52:18 Galago-Pro kernel: [  179.136350] wlp59s0: send auth to 40:e3:d6:91:5b:c2 (try 1/3)
Oct  3 17:52:18 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614338.7778] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Oct  3 17:52:18 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: Trying to associate with 40:e3:d6:91:5b:c2 (SSID='UCLA WPA' freq=2412 MHz)
Oct  3 17:52:18 Galago-Pro kernel: [  179.143418] wlp59s0: authenticated
Oct  3 17:52:18 Galago-Pro kernel: [  179.144094] wlp59s0: associate with 40:e3:d6:91:5b:c2 (try 1/3)
Oct  3 17:52:18 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614338.7927] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Oct  3 17:52:19 Galago-Pro kernel: [  179.440261] wlp59s0: associate with 40:e3:d6:91:5b:c2 (try 2/3)
Oct  3 17:52:19 Galago-Pro kernel: [  179.451229] wlp59s0: RX AssocResp from 40:e3:d6:91:5b:c2 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
Oct  3 17:52:19 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: Associated with 40:e3:d6:91:5b:c2
Oct  3 17:52:19 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Oct  3 17:52:19 Galago-Pro kernel: [  179.457153] wlp59s0: associated
Oct  3 17:52:19 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614339.1026] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Oct  3 17:52:21 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
Oct  3 17:52:22 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25 -> NAK
Oct  3 17:52:23 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
Oct  3 17:52:25 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: Authentication with 40:e3:d6:91:5b:c2 timed out.
Oct  3 17:52:25 Galago-Pro kernel: [  186.328354] wlp59s0: deauthenticating from 40:e3:d6:91:5b:c2 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Oct  3 17:52:26 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=40:e3:d6:91:5b:c2 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Oct  3 17:52:26 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="UCLA WPA" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=AUTH_FAILED
Oct  3 17:52:26 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <warn>  [1538614346.0100] sup-iface[0x5568138a4a40,wlp59s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Oct  3 17:52:26 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614346.0151] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Oct  3 17:52:26 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614346.1162] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct  3 17:52:37 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="UCLA WPA"
Oct  3 17:52:37 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 40:e3:d6:92:10:f2 (SSID='UCLA WPA' freq=5260 MHz)
Oct  3 17:52:37 Galago-Pro kernel: [  197.904131] wlp59s0: authenticate with 40:e3:d6:92:10:f2
Oct  3 17:52:37 Galago-Pro kernel: [  197.905432] wlp59s0: send auth to 40:e3:d6:92:10:f2 (try 1/3)
Oct  3 17:52:37 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: Trying to associate with 40:e3:d6:92:10:f2 (SSID='UCLA WPA' freq=5260 MHz)
Oct  3 17:52:37 Galago-Pro kernel: [  197.910563] wlp59s0: authenticated
Oct  3 17:52:37 Galago-Pro kernel: [  197.912022] wlp59s0: associate with 40:e3:d6:92:10:f2 (try 1/3)
Oct  3 17:52:37 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614357.5539] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Oct  3 17:52:37 Galago-Pro kernel: [  197.913630] wlp59s0: RX AssocResp from 40:e3:d6:92:10:f2 (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=3)
Oct  3 17:52:37 Galago-Pro kernel: [  197.915803] wlp59s0: associated
Oct  3 17:52:37 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: Associated with 40:e3:d6:92:10:f2
Oct  3 17:52:37 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Oct  3 17:52:37 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614357.5668] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Oct  3 17:52:37 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614357.5670] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Oct  3 17:52:37 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
Oct  3 17:52:37 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25 -> NAK
Oct  3 17:52:37 Galago-Pro kernel: [  198.039585] wlp59s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 40:e3:d6:92:10:f2
Oct  3 17:52:38 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
Oct  3 17:52:40 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: Authentication with 40:e3:d6:92:10:f2 timed out.
Oct  3 17:52:40 Galago-Pro kernel: [  201.002766] wlp59s0: deauthenticating from 40:e3:d6:92:10:f2 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Oct  3 17:52:40 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=40:e3:d6:92:10:f2 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Oct  3 17:52:40 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="UCLA WPA" auth_failures=2 duration=37 reason=AUTH_FAILED
Oct  3 17:52:40 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <warn>  [1538614360.6595] sup-iface[0x5568138a4a40,wlp59s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Oct  3 17:52:40 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614360.6645] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Oct  3 17:52:40 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614360.7660] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct  3 17:52:42 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <warn>  [1538614362.6410] device (wlp59s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long
Oct  3 17:52:42 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614362.6411] device (wlp59s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct  3 17:52:42 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614362.6420] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Oct  3 17:52:42 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <warn>  [1538614362.6449] device (wlp59s0): Activation: failed for connection 'UCLA WPA'
Oct  3 17:52:42 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614362.6461] device (wlp59s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct  3 17:52:42 Galago-Pro kernel: [  203.007387] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp59s0: link is not ready
Oct  3 17:52:42 Galago-Pro gnome-shell[1232]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Oct  3 17:52:42 Galago-Pro gnome-shell[1670]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Oct  3 17:52:42 Galago-Pro wpa_supplicant[1050]: wlp59s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Oct  3 17:52:43 Galago-Pro NetworkManager[1061]: <info>  [1538614363.2042] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
```

Comment: In the `terminal`, type `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog` and then try to connect to the wireless. Copy the text that appears in the terminal window, and edit it into your question. Then we'll take a look. Are you familiar with the settings on the wireless router? What security is setup there?

Comment: Thanks @heynnema I edited the opening post accordingly.  Hope that helps.

Comment: You've either got the wrong password, or one side isn't using the same WPA or WPA2 or MIXED security method. Check/change your wireless profile if need be.

Comment: Sounds like this nasty bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1748839

Comment: Ahhh there we go.  Reading the bug further it seems academic sites are impacted (Eduroam).  Interesting.  I'll have to hang tight for a fix or work around then.  :(  Thanks for the bitter sweet insight @pomsky

Comment: I'll be on campus tomorrow, I'll be sure to try that work around.  I'll post the results accordingly.  Thank you SO MUCH for the tip @pomsky !

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was having was resolved with the following settings for the WiFi network:

- WPA
- PEAP (Authentication) <--  This was the change I made. Do not check certificate * User ID is Student
- ID Anonymous ID is Student ID
- Password is...  well, my password.